# Unable to connect to Oracle 11g database using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll instead of the Microsoft System.Data.OracleClient

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to migrate a .Net 4.5.2 application from using Microsoft's deprecated  System.Data.OracleClient dll to using Oracle's own Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll (using the Nuget package v12.1.1.24160419). On the machine in question I have the Oracle client installed, and I have a tnsnames.ora file set up which the original app successfully uses to connect. I can also successfully connect with Oracle's SqlPlus and SqlDeveloper tools. However if I try to use the Oracle dll my application cannot connect.

To distill this down to the very basics I have created a very simple console application (code below) to see what is going on. If the project references the Microsoft dll (with the appropriate using statement) it will connect, but if instead I reference the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll (with the appropriate using statement) it complains about a TNS error:

> ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

I've tried adding a SERVICE_NAME clause to the tnsnames.ora file but with no improvement.

What else do I need to do?

Test app is:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace oracleconnect
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeDBConnection();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_con.State==System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                _con.Close();
            }
        }

        static private OracleConnection _con;
        private const string connectionString = "Data Source=oracledbserver2;User ID=MATTESTNHSYS;Password=thePassword";



        private static void InitializeDBConnection()
        {
            _con = new OracleConnection();
            _con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            _con.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your tnsnames file?

Comment: ORACLEDBSERVER2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = OracleDBServer2)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = orcdb10g)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` has a different search pattern to find your `tnsnames.ora` file. Unlike System.Data.OracleClient or SQL*Plus Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll does **not** read `TNS_ADMIN` value from Registry or Environment variable.

See [Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8161)

1. data source alias in the `dataSources` section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file (i.e. `machine.config`, `web.config`, `user.config`).
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

Comment: So according to that, it should suffice to place a copy of my 'working' tnsnames.ora file in the application executable folder?

Comment: Yes or make a symbolic link or define it in. NET config file

Answer (score 0):

Data Source should be defined like this:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=type_hostname)(PORT=type_port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=type_service_name_from_tsnames)))
```

And the connection string like:

```
private const string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=type_hostname)(PORT=type_port))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=type_service_name_from_tsnames)));User ID=MATTESTNHSYS;Password=thePassword";
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that. Completely different from the MS way.

Comment: @NeilHaughton Good resource is also here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/

Comment: According to that resource, my connection string should work "with TNS". I have the client installed with TNS set up (and I have a tnsnames.ora file in place that works with the Microsoft provider). It seems that the Oracle provider is not picking that up - what extra do I need to do to ensure that it finds and reads the tnsnames.ora file?

Comment: By the way I can connect using the Oracle provider and your suggested connection string, but that string assumes a tnsnames.ora file is not available. I want to make use of that file when creating the connection.